# How to return true if only one specific key in a hash has a true value (all the other values are false)

Tags: ruby, hash

For instance:

```
options = { fight: true,
 use_item: false,
 run_away: false,
 save_game: false }
```

I want a boolean expression that evaluates to `true` iff only `:fight` is `true`, and the rest are `false` (as illustrated above).

I can hack this together, but I'm trying to train myself to write more elegant ruby. Thanks!

EDIT: The hack being:

`(options[:fight] == true && options.delete(:fight).values.all {|x| !x})`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Inspired by Vitaliy's answer:

```
options[:flight] && options.values.one?
```

Comment: like that it does not destroys the hash

Comment: Sometimes it just helps to think logically what your trying to accomplish. Excellent approach +1.

Answer (score 9):

Assuming all values are strictly boolean, it's as simple as:

```
options == {fight: true, use_item: false, run_away: false, save_game: false}
```

[See documentation for the == method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-3D-3D)

Comment: Yup I know how to do that, but is there a general solution? There may be more options passed in, and I want to return true only if fight: is true and the rest are false.

Comment: I can't come up with anything more succint than @Shawn Balestracci's answer for that.

Comment: As far as I understand, they should not be ignored, but they should all be `false`

Answer (score 2):

I think your hack is not bad. It can be simplified a little bit though:

```
options.delete(:flight) && options.values.none?
```

Comment: +1 For elegance. However, it will also return true if `:flight` is _anything_ other than `nil` or `false`.

Comment: Plus it destroys the options hash (although it might not be important in this case)

Answer (score 1):

```
options.find_all{|k,v| v } == [[:fight, true]]
```

or

```
options.values.count(true) == 1 && options[:fight]
```

Comment: Not exactly "more elegant" than the hack they are already using, IMHO.

Comment: oh I liked the count(true) one best, though this one is interesting.

Comment: Same thing, but (5 characters ;)) shorter: `options.select {|_,v| v}.keys == [:fight]`

Comment: @tessi, it's not the same thing. Priti is explicitly checking for `true` instead of truthiness.  The OP might not "false" to be true.

Comment: Har! You're right. With the example given, I assumed all values are boolean.

Comment: @ShawnBalestracci Is it ok?

Comment: I don't like the _ as you don't know what the previous command is, but yes they both otherwise work.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
options.all? {|k,v| k == :fight ? v : !v}
```

For a more general approach:

```
def is_action?(options, action)
  options.all? {|k,v| k == action ? v : !v}
end

is_action? options, :fight
# => true
```

Answer (score 1):

This one is independent of number of key/elems in the hash.

```
options[:fight] && options.find_all{|arr| !arr[1]}.size == options.size-1
```

Also Just a tip, in ruby, you never need to write something like:

```
options[:fight] == true
```

Answer (score 0):

```
options.select{ |k, v| v } == [[:fight, true]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you control the content of the hash, and it is relatively small, I would use something like this in a private method as a generic solution.

```
def exclusively_true?(hash, key)
  return false unless hash.delete(key) == true
  !hash.has_value? true
end

require 'test/unit'
class TestExclusive < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def setup
    @test_hash = {foo: true, bar: false, hoge: false}
  end
  def test_exclusive
    assert_equal(true, exclusively_true?(@test_hash, :foo))
  end
  def test_inexclusive
    @test_hash[:bar] = true
    assert_equal(false, exclusively_true?(@test_hash, :foo))
  end
end

require 'benchmark'

h = {foo: true}
999.times {|i| h["a#{i}"] = false}
Benchmark.bmbm(30) do |x|
  x.report('exclusively_true') do
    1000.times do
      exclusively_true?(h, :foo)
    end
  end
end
```

**Contrived benchmarks:  (OS X 10.8.3 / 3 GHz / 8 GB)**

```
ruby -v: ruby 2.0.0p0 (2013-02-24 revision 39474) [x86_64-darwin12.3.0]
Rehearsal ------------------------------------------------------------------
exclusively_true                 0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000412)
--------------------------------------------------------- total: 0.000000sec

                                     user     system      total        real
exclusively_true                 0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000331)
```

Comment: you can make that shorter with "hash.delete(key) == true && !hash.has_value?(true)" but establishing the reject case up front will help future developers read your code. Readability and optimization is far more important than clever one liners.